# Getting NaN instead of numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, nan, alphabetical

I am trying to get a range of numbers by converting alphabet to numbers and then comparing them with one another to see if they match or not.
I can change my approach but I don't understand *why* is it happening.

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  let left=0
  let right=str.length-1
  for(let i in str) {

    let alphaNum=str.charCodeAt(i) //gives number
    let alphaNum2=str.charCodeAt(i+1) //gives 98 for the first and then NaN for the rest

    console.log(i, alphaNum, alphaNum2)
  }
  

}
fearNotLetter("abce")
fearNotLetter("abcdefghjklmno")
```

Comment: `i` are strings since `for`–`in` iterates property keys and these numeric property keys are strings. `i + 1` performs string concatenation. Would’ve been easy to debug by simply logging what `i` and `i + 1` are.

Comment: Better alternative: `Array.from("abcdefghjklmno", (char, index, string) => { const alphaNum = char.codePointAt(), alphaNum2 = string.codePointAt(index + 1);`…`});`. Note that you’ll have to handle the last index, at which the index `index + 1` doesn’t exist, in some way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert string to integer, for-in loop gives string as key:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  let left=0
  let right=str.length-1
  str.split().forEach((char, i) => {

    let alphaNum=str.charCodeAt(i) //gives number
    let alphaNum2=str.charCodeAt(i+1) //gives 98 for the first and then NaN for the rest


  });
  

}
// fearNotLetter("abce")
fearNotLetter("abcdefghjklmno")
```

Comment: so the index i'm getting is the string itsef and not a number?

Comment: Using parseInt will NOT fix the code, because `i` will not only loop over the indexes (as strings), but also some string method names! Just paste this code into Chrome console and see for yourself: `const str = "abc"; for (let i in str) { console.log(i, typeof(i)); }`

Comment: @kol true. so what should be the efficient solution then?

Comment: use ForEach loop, updated my answer

Comment: `forEach` is OK, but there is also no problem with using `for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)` :)

Answer (score 1):

The for-in loop iterates over the enumerable properties of the string. It starts with the indexes: `"0"`, `"1"`, etc., but they will be strings, so adding `1` will append `"1"`, and `i + 1` will be `"01"`, `"11"`, `"21"` etc. When you call `charCodeAt` with these, they will be converted to numbers: `1`, `11`, `21` etc. and `charCodeAt` returns `NaN` for out-of range index values.